# How to set TextView font family to use the system setting currently enabled on the android device?

Tags: java, android

so currently I'm trying to create an android app and I want my textviews, buttons, pretty much everything with text displayed to use the font used by the system. How can I access the font being used by the system? Since users can change the system font I want to make sure the app matches the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a textview, you can the the current Typeface by calling:

```
Typeface currentTypeface = textView.getTypeFace()
```

Lookup TextView in the Android docs.